# Remote PostgreSQL Access

Tags: performance, postgresql, security

I have Server with a Postgres DB on the same server is a contentmanager application which writes into the psql db. Further I have an other server with a application which fetchs data from the postgresql (read only).
I know there are different ways to get remote access from my app server to the postgres server:

1. Access over internet with IP Whitelisting
2. Access over a SSH Tunnel
3. Fetching data over a webservice which runs local on the PSQL Server.

Which solution is the most performant and securest?
Or is there any other solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will put it short.

- Option 1 makes sure noone else connects to your server, but does not
  protect your connection in any other way.
- Option 2 provides full security.
- Option 3 has a lot of latency, though can be as secure as SSH (if you
  use HTTPS).

So use SSH tunnel. It's a sure way.

Comment: What is the best way to create the ssl tunnel to guarantee that the connections is always open. Eg after a network hick - up. 
Should I create the Tunnel directly in the application? My Application is in python

Comment: I usually create SSH tunnels with a command like `ssh -fNg -L 5599:127.0.0.1:5432 user@mysesrver`. You can set a cronjob to run the command if the tunnel fails (i.e. `ps ax | grep ssh` returns nothing).